# Cardinality of the set of functions that maps $\mathbb{R}$ to $\{1\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $F$ be the set of functions that map the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ to the set $\{1\}$.

What is the cardinality of $F$?

I know (I think) $F$ has at least the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$, but is it greater?

Comment: How exactly do you figure that $F$ has at least the cardinality of $\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 2):

A function $f: X \to \{1\}$ with codomain a one point set, there always is exactly one such function, namely the one that sends every element of the domain to that point, 1.

Answer (score 1):

You are considering the set $S$ of functions
$$S = \{F\ \colon\Bbb{R}\to \{1\}\ |\ \text{ F is a function}\}.$$
You can also denote this set by $\{1\}^{\Bbb{R}}$, following the convention that $A^B$ denotes the set of all functions from $B$ to $A$. You have:
$$|\{1\}^{\Bbb{R}}| = |\{1\}|^{|\Bbb{R}|} = 1^{|\Bbb{R}|}=1.$$
This can also be seen directly from the definition of $S$: There is only one function $F$ that maps $\Bbb{R}$ to $\{1\}$, namely $F(x) = 1$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$. The reason is that there is only one element in the codomain, so all real numbers must map to this element.